# Detox UI Testing - Tests time out when running on CI

Tags: react-native, gitlab-ci, detox

I'm running react-native android integration tests headlessly using the detox framework on Ubuntu 18.04.

The line that I use to run my test suite as a whole is: 
`detox test -c android.emu.ci --headless --cleanup --take-screenshots failing --detectOpenHandles`. This runs 7 tests.

When I run the tests like this the first test runs successfully, and then the second test fails, as it seems like the [emulator is offline](https://gist.github.com/juddey/b94ccd9b721273d839e302087edb7f06#file-trace-txt-L586).

If I run the tests individually with a 15 second gap between them eg:

```
    - detox test post.spec.js -c android.emu.ci --headless --cleanup --take-screenshots failing --detectOpenHandles
    - sleep 15s
    - detox test post.report.spec.js -c android.emu.ci --headless --cleanup --take-screenshots failing --detectOpenHandles
    - sleep 15s
```

They all complete without failing, so the tests are not the culprit.

I have tried adding a sleep in the afterEach for each test, and as the last action in each test, but neither of these have been successful.

I'm looking for suggestions/direction on what to do to get the tests to wait for the emulator to be ready before executing.

Comment: Please follow https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md#identifying-which-synchronization-mechanism-causes-us-to-wait-too-much, specifically the `-detoxPrintBusyIdleResources YES` recommendation.

Comment: Thanks @LeoNatan, I had a read of the docs, from my read those debugging flags apply to iOS/OSX only. I'm running the test suite on ubuntu 18.04 using an android emulator.

However, I did find this for linux: `--debug-synchronization 200` which I added, and got these [results](https://gist.github.com/juddey/05ef76dd3f5c94a5eef99dfda37eebf6). You can see the process is still not finding any emulators.

Aside: In the time between posting this issue and this comment I have got these tests working perfectly on iOS, with `- detox test -c ios.emu.release --take-screenshots failing --cleanup` :)

Comment: Ah, apologies, missed that this was on Android. If you don't come up with a solution, I suggest you open an issue on the Detox tracker, and we'll take a look at it. Provide as much information as needed. Thanks

Comment: where to add this `-detoxPrintBusyIdleResources YES` ?